# Тестовая задачка Яндекса

Tags: база-данных, mysql, запрос, sql

Есть таблица следующего вида:

```
CREATE TABLE track_downloads (
  download_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  track_id INT NOT NULL,
  user_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  download_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

  PRIMARY KEY (download_id)
);
```

Надо написать SQL-запрос, возвращающий все пары (download_count, user_count), удовлетворяющие следующему условию: user_count — общее ненулевое число пользователей, сделавших ровно download_count скачиваний.

Пытаюсь сделать что то вроде :

```
select distinct count(*) as download_count, count('download_count') as user_count from download group by user_id, 'user_count';
```

То есть первая группировка должна быть по user_id, а вторая по download_count..Но как это сделать в одном запросе? Помогите с правильным запросом пжлст.

Comment: @Alexey2012, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так:

```
select distinct download_count, count(*) as user_count
from (
    select count(*) as download_count, user_id 
    from track_downloads 
    group by user_id)
group by download_count
```

Comment: Это какая-то магия ?  

    group by user_id group by user_id

Comment: Поправил, случайно дважды получилось.

Comment: Правильное решение следующее:

select distinct download_count, count(*) as user_count
from (
    select count(*) as download_count 
    from track_downloads
    group by user_id) 
as download_count
group by download_count;